# RKResponseDescriptor vs RKRouter

Tags: ios, ios6, restkit

So I am a bit confused as to what are the differences of these two features, or at least, how to merge them together. I have this situation where I have this descriptor:

```
RKResponseDescriptor *responsePlant = 
    [RKResponseDescriptor
        responseDescriptorWithMapping:plantMapping
                          pathPattern:@"/api/rest/plants/:plant_id"
                              keyPath:nil
                          statusCodes:RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful)];
```

Now, I would like to do something like this

```
RKResponseDescriptor *responsePlantAll = 
    [RKResponseDescriptor
        responseDescriptorWithMapping:plantMapping
                          pathPattern:@"/api/rest/plants/"
                              keyPath:@"objects"
                          statusCodes:RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful)];
```

**Note the keyPath is nil in one place, and not in the other**.

This works... but it is a lot of copy pasting for nothing. Can I use RKRouter for that?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You call two different paths so using two different `RKResponseDescriptor` makes perfect sense to me!

> I also would like to know if you can or should use RKRouter with
>   RKResponseDescriptor?

I really recommend using Routes. With them, all my paths are centralized in my `RKObjectManager` subclass, so if I have to change a path I don't have to look everywhere!